# Cursor pointer in OpenLayers on hover

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-6

Using the latest version of OpenLayers with React. Trying to change the cursor to pointer in the following way:

```
function mapOnMove(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) return;
        const pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        const hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
        evt.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
}
```

In development everything works as expecting. Cursor turns into pointer on feature hover.
However, after using build script, and serving static files - cursor pointer doesn't work.
Tried to look for the reasons and couldn't find anything appropriate. Maybe someone has any ideas.